# I need some assistance with creating a certain shape / pattern

Tags: c++

I am trying to make this pattern

[image]

But i cannot seem to get the hang of it.

I did the first part here is my code

This is my current output so far

Enter number of rows: 4

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******

*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

This is my current output and i only need to add the mid part between them.I need some assistance with that.any help is appreciated.
My current output is a bit off with the spacing.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri my output is more than that but I cannot post an image due to my reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your code into functions. Then your main function should look like this

```
int main() {
    const auto rows = []() {std::size_t r; std::cin >> r; return r;}();
    printHeader(rows);
    printDashes(rows);
    printMid(rows);
    printDashes(rows);
    printFooter(rows);
    return 0;
}
```

The  first pyramid can be printed with

```
void printStarsLine(const std::size_t row, const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t stars = 1 + 2 * row;
    const std::size_t spaces = 2 * rows - row;

    std::cout << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << std::string(stars, '*')
              << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << '\n';
}

void printHeader(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printStarsLine(i, rows);
    }
}
```

The bottom pyramid is the top pyramid reverted

```
void printFooter(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {rows}; i > 0; --i) {
        printStarsLine(i - 1, rows);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The dashes are simple dashes

```
void printDashes(const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t dashes = 2 * rows + 1;

    std::cout << std::string(rows, ' ')
              << std::string(dashes, '-')
              << std::string(rows, ' ')
              << '\n';
}
```

and the middle part can be printed with

```
void printMidLine(const std::size_t row, const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t spaces = rows - 1 - row;

    std::cout << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << std::string(row + 1, '*')
              << '|'
              << std::string(2 * rows - 1, '*')
              << '|'
              << std::string(row + 1, '*')
              << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << '\n';
}

void printMid(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(i, rows);
    }
    for (std::size_t i {1}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(rows - i - 1, rows);
    }
}
```

The whole code is

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printStarsLine(const std::size_t row, const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t stars = 1 + 2 * row;
    const std::size_t spaces = 2 * rows - row;

    std::cout << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << std::string(stars, '*')
              << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << '\n';
}

void printHeader(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printStarsLine(i, rows);
    }
}

void printFooter(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {rows}; i > 0; --i) {
        printStarsLine(i - 1, rows);
    }
}

void printDashes(const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t dashes = 2 * rows + 1;

    std::cout << std::string(rows, ' ')
              << std::string(dashes, '-')
              << std::string(rows, ' ')
              << '\n';
}

void printMidLine(const std::size_t row, const std::size_t rows) {
    const std::size_t spaces = rows - 1 - row;

    std::cout << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << std::string(row + 1, '*')
              << '|'
              << std::string(2 * rows - 1, '*')
              << '|'
              << std::string(row + 1, '*')
              << std::string(spaces, ' ')
              << '\n';
}

void printMid(const std::size_t rows) {
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(i, rows);
    }
    for (std::size_t i {1}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(rows - i - 1, rows);
    }
}

int main() {
    const auto rows = []() {std::size_t r; std::cin >> r; return r;}();
    printHeader(rows);
    printDashes(rows);
    printMid(rows);
    printDashes(rows);
    printFooter(rows);
    return 0;
}
```

The line

```
printMid(rows);
```

can be replaced with

```
for (int i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
    const int spaces = rows - 1 - i;
    for (int j {0}; j < spaces; ++j) {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    for (int j {0}; j < i + 1; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int j {0}; j < 2 * rows - 1; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int j {0}; j < i + 1; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    for (int j {0}; j < spaces; ++j) {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
for (int i {1}; i < rows; ++i) {
    const int spaces = i;
    for (int j {0}; j < spaces; ++j) {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    for (int j {0}; j < rows - i; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int j {0}; j < 2 * rows - 1; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int j {0}; j < rows - i; ++j) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    for (int j {0}; j < spaces; ++j) {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new.Is string (spaces, " ") a function that takes two parameters.Thanks for the help.Can i make the middle part like the rest using a for loop without creating a function.I have been to programming for 2 weeks so i still did not learn const auto.Thanks for the code i will try to analyze the code and find the mid point loop.

Comment: If you are fresh to C++ you should avoid cstrings like `const char *b` and use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead. Cstrings can be very complex and even teachers make errors using them. `std::string` is the C++ way to work with text. Of course you could replace each function call with the corresponding function body but I claim that functions are easier to understand. You can replace `const auto` with `const std::size_t` at this point.

Comment: can i know what the for loop for the mid part would look like.Like the equation. Eg as for the first part   for (int i = 1, k = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0)
    {
        for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
        {
            cout << *b;
        }
        while (k != 2 * i - 1)
        {
            cout << *c;
            ++k;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

Comment: Notice the difference between `' '` and `" "`. In my code the constructor `std::string` is called with two parameters and the second is a char `' '` and not a const char array `" "`.

Comment: because the code for the mid part is a bit confusing.I still have to learn size t.I will do a quick search for it.Thanks for responding

Comment: The function for the mid part contains two for loops: `for (std::size_t i {0}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(i, rows);
    }`  and `for (std::size_t i {1}; i < rows; ++i) {
        printMidLine(rows - i - 1, rows);
    }`

Comment: yeah i saw that.I mean i i were to go For(int i=0; i<rows;i++){ } what should i keep in these bracket if i were not to use a function.And i not asked to use size t sinnce i did not learn it.I am supposed to make the mid part with nested loop like the first and the last part. can i know the nested loop for it.

Comment: if i were not to put this functions in the loop print midline and not use the size t what is supposed to be between the { }. and wanted to ask what string(row , ' * ') will do.Is it a function.

Comment: I added an alternative code without `std::size_t`, `std::string` and functions but as you can see this makes the code unreadable.

Comment: i modified the current code.Could you take a look at it. The output is a bit off with spacing.Could you help me with that.Sorry for wasting a lot of your time.You already help me a lot.Thanks again

Comment: `for (space = i; space < rows; space++)` => `for (space = i; space < 2 * rows + 1; space++)` and `for (int space = 0; space < rows - i; ++space)` => `for (int space = 0; space < 2 * rows + 1 - i; ++space)`

Comment: this is for the last and first part am i right.Thanks for replying.

Comment: Thanks for all the help